# wget giving error when downloading certain files

Tags: command-line, wget

I am facing a problem in downloading some documents programmatically.

For example this link

```
https://www-950.ibm.com/events/wwe/grp/grp019.nsf/vLookupPDFs/Introduction_to_Storwize_V7000_Unified_T3/$file/Introduction_to_Storwize_V7000_Unified_T3.pdf
```

can be downloaded from browser, but when I try to get it from wget it doesn't work.

I have tried

```
wget https://www-950.ibm.com/events/wwe/grp/grp004.nsf/vLookupPDFs/3-Mobile%20Platform%20--%20Truty%20--%20March%208%202012/\$file/3-Mobile%20Platform%20--%20Truty%20--%20March%208%202012.pdf
```

It gave me this output

```
--2012-04-18 17:09:42--  
https://www-950.ibm.com/events/wwe/grp/grp004.nsf/vLookupPDFs/3-Mobile%20Platform%20--%20Truty%20--%20March%208%202012/$file/3-Mobile%20Platform%20--%20Truty%20--%20March%208%202012.pdf

Resolving www-950.ibm.com... 216.208.176.98
Connecting to www-950.ibm.com|216.208.176.98|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Can any one help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the --no-check-certificate to your original wget command.

Plus you need to ensure that you are using a proxy.

On Linux:

```
export http_proxy=http://myproxyserver.com:8080
```

On Windows:

```
set http_proxy=http://myproxyserver.com:8080
```

I also found that on windows, because this is a https request, that in order to make it work, I also had to set https_proxy.  So

```
set https_proxy=http://myproxyserver.com:8080
```

Obviously, change the proxy settings to suite your particular situation.